# Подключения Google Play Service к проекту Unity3D. (Ошибка "authentication failed - developer error")

Tags: unity3d

Люди добрые, столкнулся с проблемой, которая застопорила меня уже как на неделю. Дело в общем вот какое : Решил я значиться подключить к игре Google Service. Вроде всё настроил, и все коды ввёл правильно. OAuth2 настроил. Запускаю : Игра запускается, после на секунду зависает и темнеет экран (Прям видно что идёт попытка подключения), отвисает и ничего. Вообще ничего. Прогнал через Logcat, получил вот такой лог:

05/10 10:33:23.005 3905 3925 Info Unity MemoryManager: Using 'Dynamic Heap' Allocator.
05/10 10:33:23.098 3905 3925 Info Unity SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 4, Memory = 1859mb
05/10 10:33:23.098 3905 3925 Info Unity SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf), 0 little (mask: 0x0)
05/10 10:33:23.099 3905 3925 Info Unity ApplicationInfo com.DynastyOfGames.FactoryTime version 5.1k build a567197b-59d8-4278-b40f-b05e50ceb2c2
05/10 10:33:23.099 3905 3925 Info Unity Built from '2019.4/release' branch, Version '2019.4.20f1 (6dd1c08eedfa)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Enabled'
05/10 10:33:23.435 3905 3925 Debug Unity  GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT
05/10 10:33:23.435 3905 3925 Debug Unity _texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
05/10 10:33:29.109 3905 3966 Warn Unity The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Main Camera') is missing!
05/10 10:33:29.109 3905 3966 Warn Unity (Filename:  Line: 334)
05/10 10:33:29.109 3905 3966 Warn Unity
05/10 10:33:29.110 3905 3966 Warn Unity The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Main Camera') is missing!
05/10 10:33:29.110 3905 3966 Warn Unity (Filename:  Line: 334)
05/10 10:33:29.110 3905 3966 Warn Unity
05/10 10:33:29.133 3905 3966 Warn Unity The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Игра') is missing!
05/10 10:33:29.133 3905 3966 Warn Unity (Filename:  Line: 334)
05/10 10:33:29.133 3905 3966 Warn Unity
05/10 10:33:29.214 3905 3925 Info Unity Starting Auth with token client.
05/10 10:33:29.214 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
05/10 10:33:29.214 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient:Authenticate(Boolean, Action`1) 05/10 10:33:29.214 3905 3925 Info Unity   05/10 10:33:29.214 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:29.214 3905 3925 Info Unity 05/10 10:33:29.279 3905 3925 Info Unity Starting Auth with token client. 05/10 10:33:29.279 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:29.279 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient:Authenticate(Boolean, Action`1)
05/10 10:33:29.279 3905 3925 Info Unity UIscript:Start()
05/10 10:33:29.279 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:29.279 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
05/10 10:33:29.279 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:29.287 3905 3925 Info Unity Starting Auth with token client.
05/10 10:33:29.287 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
05/10 10:33:29.287 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient:Authenticate(Boolean, Action`1) 05/10 10:33:29.287 3905 3925 Info Unity Auntification:Start() 05/10 10:33:29.287 3905 3925 Info Unity   05/10 10:33:29.287 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:29.287 3905 3925 Info Unity 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity Returning an error code. 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.Android.<>c__DisplayClass18_0:<Authenticate>b__0(Int32) 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T) 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo) 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy:Invoke(String, Object[]) 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper:InvokeJavaProxyMethod(AndroidJavaProxy, IntPtr, IntPtr) 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity   05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:29.438 3905 3925 Info Unity 05/10 10:33:29.455 3905 3925 Warn Unity !!! [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/10/21 10:33:29 +05:00 WARNING: PlayGamesPlatform already initialized. Ignoring this call. 05/10 10:33:29.455 3905 3925 Warn Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:29.455 3905 3925 Warn Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/10 10:33:29.455 3905 3925 Warn Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/10 10:33:29.455 3905 3925 Warn Unity   05/10 10:33:29.455 3905 3925 Warn Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:29.455 3905 3925 Warn Unity 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/10/21 10:33:29 +05:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform. 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity   05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/10/21 10:33:29 +05:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity   05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:29.456 3905 3925 Info Unity 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity Returning an error code. 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.Android.<>c__DisplayClass18_0:<Authenticate>b__0(Int32) 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T) 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo) 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy:Invoke(String, Object[]) 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper:InvokeJavaProxyMethod(AndroidJavaProxy, IntPtr, IntPtr) 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity   05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:29.459 3905 3925 Info Unity 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity Returning an error code. 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.Android.<>c__DisplayClass18_0:<Authenticate>b__0(Int32) 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T) 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo) 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy:Invoke(String, Object[]) 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper:InvokeJavaProxyMethod(AndroidJavaProxy, IntPtr, IntPtr) 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity   05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:31.823 3905 3905 Info Unity 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity Oh no 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`2:Invoke(T1, T2) 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.<>c__DisplayClass33_0:<Authenticate>b__0(SignInStatus) 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T) 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke() 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity   05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 05/10 10:33:31.839 3905 3925 Info Unity 05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity Oh no! 05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) 05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`2:Invoke(T1, T2) 05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.<>c__DisplayClass33_0:<Authenticate>b__0(SignInStatus) 05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke()
05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
05/10 10:33:31.846 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:31.857 3905 3925 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/10/21 10:33:31 +05:00 DEBUG: Authentication failed - developer error
05/10 10:33:31.857 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
05/10 10:33:31.857 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke()
05/10 10:33:31.857 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
05/10 10:33:31.857 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:31.857 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
05/10 10:33:31.857 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/10/21 10:33:31 +05:00 DEBUG: Authentication failed - developer error
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke()
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity  [Play Games Plugin 0.10.12] 05/10/21 10:33:31 +05:00 DEBUG: Authentication canceled
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity System.Action:Invoke()
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
05/10 10:33:31.858 3905 3925 Info Unity

Единственное за что смог уцепиться глаз, это уже выше описанная ошибка "authentication failed - developer error". Вопрошаю к вашему милосердию, и сохраняю надежду в то, что найдутся люди которые помогут.

Comment: Я лично подключал сервисы по видео Android helper, они работают.

Answer (score 0):

Окей. Эта ошибка решается максимально просто. Если кто-то столкнулся с такой же, вам необходимо полностью удалить ассет гугл плея из юнити (сами папки из проекта), и переустановить.